# What is the Big Oh, Big Omega and Big Theta of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am reading The algorithm design manual and i am stucked at this question[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uiq4.png)

I thought big oh is O(nlogn), but I'm not sure, and what about Omega and Theta?

Answer (score 0):

Here in the description **TIME (t)** has taken as key to define the complexity while the other key would be **SPACE(s)** as well.

**Theoretical Analysis Of Time Efficiency**

- Time efficiency is analyzed by determining the number of repetitions
  of the **basic operation** as a function of **input size**
- **Basic operation:** the operation that contributes most towards the
  running time of the algorithm C(n)

[image]

**Growth of Functions and Aymptotic Notation**

- When we study algorithms, we are interested in characterizing them
  according to their efficiency.
- We are usually interesting in the order of growth of the running time
  of an algorithm, not in the exact running time. This is also referred
  to as the asymptotic running time.
- We need to develop a way to talk about rate of growth of functions
  so that we can compare algorithms.
- Asymptotic notation gives us a method for classifying functions
  according to their rate of growth.

**1. Big-O Notation**

- **Definition:** f (n) = O(g(n)) iff there are two positive constants c
  and n0 such that

  ```
         f (n)| ≤ c |g(n)| for all n ≥ n0
  ```
- If f (n) is nonnegative, we can simplify the last condition to

  ```
          0 ≤ f (n) ≤ c g(n) for all n ≥ n0
  ```
- We say that

  **f(n) is big-O of g(n)**

As **n** increases, **f (n)** grows no faster than **g(n)**. In other words, **g(n)** is an ***asymptotic upper bound*** on **f (n)**.

[image]

**2. Ω notation**

- Definition: f (n) = Ω(g(n)) iff there are two positive constants c and n0 such that

  ```
       f (n)| ≥ c |g(n)| for all n ≥ n0
  ```
- If f (n) is nonnegative, we can simplify the last condition to

  ```
       0 ≤ c g(n) ≤ f (n) for all n ≥ n0
  ```
- We say that

  **f (n) is omega of g(n)**

As **n** increases, **f(n)** grows no slower than **g(n)**. In other words, **g(n)** is an ***asymptotic lower bound*** on **f(n)**.

[image]

**3. Θ notation**

- Definition: f (n) = Θ(g(n)) iff there are three positive constants
  c1, c2 and n0 such that

  ```
            c1|g(n)| ≤ |f (n)| ≤ c2|g(n)| for all n ≥ n0
  ```
- If f(n) is nonnegative, we can simplify the last condition to

  ```
            0 ≤ c1 g(n) ≤ f (n) ≤ c2 g(n) for all n ≥ n0
  ```
- We say that

  **f(n) is theta of g(n)**

As **n** increases, **f(n)** grows at the same rate as **g(n)**. In other words, **g(n)** is an ***asymptotically tight bound*** on **f(n)**.

[image]

Comment: That was not an answer to my question, i asked the complexity of an algoirithm, and I know the definition of Big-Oh, Big-Omega and Big-Theta

Comment: Okay! I didn't see the url of algo which you have posted in question. My answer is only based on the text message.I am putting solution for it

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity for the given algorithm would be

[image]

As per the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

[image]

The upper and lower bound for above function:

[image]

Thus, we get

[image]